# ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration equivalent for FW 3.5 and 4.0?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, frameworks, configurationmanager

I'm trying to get the LocalAppData default folder for my program

But this only works for FrameWork 4.5:

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming).FilePath
```

I need a way to do it in Framework 3.5 and framework 4.0.

PS: In VB.NET

Thankyou for read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is defined from .NET Framework 2.0.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms134265(v=vs.110).aspx => Version Information

Regards, Jörg